# Joomfish translation issues

Tags: joomla, translation, arabic, joomfish

I have been working on a site which is bilingual(Eng/Arb).......english part is done and perfect and when iam using joomfish component to translate it in arabic im having issue like

when i go like joomfish - > translation - > languages - > selected arb - > content elements - > content - > and when i select an article or topic it is not displaying the original english text to be translated in arabic.....and i know this is not correct coz i have done this kind of translation before where always there is orginal english text which has to be translated and a text editor below to do it in arabic.......but not getting why it is not showing like this on the site which im working on right now and i dont know what iam missing here.....

any help/advise is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Manage Translations/"Copy original to language" option?

Comment: this solved the issue ....but some how i doubt whether this is the proper way to solve this issue, there has to be some other way.......Neways it is solved for now thanks a lot for help :)